# R: Write function to change types table columns

Tags: r, csv

Let's say you have several CSV tables like

```
Foo Date1 Date2
bar 2010-03-05 2023-09-09
...
[table1]
```

or

```
Foobar Date
baz 2042-01-01
[table2]
```

After parsing those tables using read.csv, I'd like to convert the colulumns containing Dates to the internal date type.

One could do this with

```
table1$Date1 <- as.Date(table1$Date1, "%Y-%m-%d")
table1$Date2 <- as.Date(table1$Date2, "%Y-%m-%d")
table2$Date <- as.Date(table2$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

But that produces a lot of redundant code, so I'd like to write a function that takes a table and a variadic number of columns and rearranges the table. Just something convenient like:

```
convertDate(table1, Date1, Date2)
convertDate(table2, Date)
```

But how to define convertDate?

I already tried (in a simple one-argument case) sth. like:

```
convertDate <- function(table, column) {
  table[[column]] <- as.Date(table[[column]], "%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

But this doesn't work, as R apparently passes the table argument by value and not by reference...

What's the most R-like way to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You'd need `substitute` or the like. You can parse multiple columns at the same time by subsetting with brackets, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lapply would work here

```
tbl <- data.frame(bar = 1, Date1 = "2010-03-05", Date2 = "2023-09-09", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(tbl)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ bar  : num 1
# $ Date1: chr "2010-03-05"
# $ Date2: chr "2023-09-09"

tbl[, -1] <- as.data.frame(lapply(tbl[, -1], as.Date))
str(tbl)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ bar  : num 1
# $ Date1: Date, format: "2010-03-05"
# $ Date2: Date, format: "2023-09-09"
```

As a function:

```
convertDate <- function(table, columns) {
 table[, columns] <- as.data.frame(lapply(table[, columns, drop = FALSE], as.Date))
 return(table)
}
```

Comment: Yes, this looks like the solution I was looking for. Besides the fact, the I have to reassign the variable like 'a <- convertDate(a, "foo")'. But I think R is not able to pass by reference...

Comment: This does accept an arbitrary number of columns, without the need for ellipses. You can enter `columns = 2:3` for example or `columns = c("Date1", "Date2")` if you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, just recognized it. You're absolutely right.

Comment: Btw if you do not want to reassign you can use <<- in a function which would assign the variable in the parent environment. Try it out: `foo <- function() x <<- 1`. However, in this case I would use assign and substitute with parse to assign

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a list of column names and iterate over it. I am attaching sample code below.

```
convertDate <- function(table, columns) {
  for (column in columns){
    table[[column]] <- as.Date(table[[column]], "%Y-%m-%d")
  }
  return(table)
}
table2 = data.frame(Date='2042-01-01')
class(table2$Date)
table2 = convertDate(table2, 'Date')
class(table2$Date)
table1 = data.frame(Date1='2010-03-05', Date2='2023-09-09')
class(table1$Date1)
table1 = convertDate(table1, list('Date1','Date2'))
class(table1$Date1)
class(table1$Date2)
```

Comment: I'm going to accept NBATrends anwser, as the answer doesn't require any loops. Nevertheless, your answer works fine and is correct, as well.